# Sql using OR in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, select, case, conditional-statements

I need to check if a word that starts with a vowel and write 'an' or 'a' accordingly.

I could just go and write:

```
CASE substring(word, 1, 1) when 'a' then write an when 'i' write an
```

and so on.

Anyone has an easier way to do it? Just say if it's `a`, `i`, `o`, `u` or `e` - write 'an' else write 'a'?

Comment: not about problem but result will probably wrong if string is 'university'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN substring(word, 1, 1) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
         THEN 'an'
  -- WHEN 

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(CASE WHEN left(word, 1) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')  THEN 'an' ELSE 'a' END)
```